# What happens when I never call shutdown on ExecutorService?

Tags: java, android, executorservice

I'm trying to use ExecutorService for an Android project. I need it to be running for the duration of the application, and shutdown when the application shuts down. The problem is, on Android, detecting the shutdown of an application is a bit tricky. So what would happen if I never shutdown ExecutorService on an Android application?

Comment: You mean when the app is *really* shut down, as in when it's completely terminated?  Or do you mean when it's still running but just not in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when I never call shutdown on ExecutorService?

you will waste some resources it keeps - how large those resources are depends on your executor. You can read in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html): *"An unused executorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources."*

> The problem is, on Android, detecting the shutdown of an application is a bit tricky

actually you should never shutdown your app process yourself, there are ways for doing this - but they are regarder as antipatterns. You normally "close" android app by closing all activities, or by implementing double back idiom on start activity. Its better to think that android app runs all the time after it is started. By closing all the activities your process might still be running for long time. Android might kill your process after some time, or keep it for long time.

> So what would happen if I never shutdown ExecutorService on an Android application?

waste of resources, android might be more likely kill your process making it longer for your app to be started next time (but how much longer, I have no idea) - but as always it depends on your application.

If you for some reasons you dont control incoming tasks - then by shuting down your executor you also prevent new tasks to be processed when your app should be closed, you can find method for this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

This might be usefull when your executor is inside service, and you want to stop that service. Then its suggested to gracefully release resoures. Also you might have some code that depends on all tasks to be finished, etc...